# 2 divs positioned absolute, one is blocking the other

Tags: html, css, position, center, absolute

I have 2 divs, both with the same width, positioned absolute, centered horizontally and vertically on the page.

Each div contains a link. However only one link is clickable. I need both links to be clickable.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jVm2/9/)

```
<div class="button"> <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">button</a> </div>
<div class="arrows"> <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">arrows</a> </div> 

.button, .arrows {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 520px;
 height: 240px;
 margin: auto !important; 
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
.button { z-index: 999; }
.arrows { text-align: center; z-index:99999; }
.button a { border: 1px solid red; }
.arrows a { border: 1px solid yellow; }
```

Any tips would be truly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't position them on top of each other. I'm not sure what you are trying to do but this HTML/CSS is probably the wrong approach.

Comment: why would you position your divs in absolute? Why not put the two links in a single div? Explain what you are trying to do here

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both `div`s take up the entire space of the box, so it'll be impossible for both to be clickable.

The solution is to have a single `div` container that is the box, and have the button and arrow `a`s be smaller elements within the container:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="button" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">button</a>
    <div class="arrow"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">arrows</a></div>
</div>
```

In order to maintain the same look, we need to have an arrow container that will center the link for the arrow. The button link will be `position: absolute` to allow both links to exist on the same line.

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 520px;
    height: 240px;
    margin: auto !important;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.arrow a {    
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.button {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

See the updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jVm2/14/)**.

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from you setting the divs to the same width and height, the second div is covering the first div so clicks won't fall through.

If you want that border you need a parent div.

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/6qXAm/

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="button"> <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">button</a> </div>
<div class="arrows"> <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">arrows</a> </div>    
</div>

.parent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 520px;
    height: 240px;
    margin: auto !important; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Works great, however wrapping everything in a parent div is not possible as the arrows div is being loaded dynamically else where on the page.

Comment: Why can you not add the arrow div dynamically into a parent container?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going to post another answer because this one takes a completely different approach.

CSS allows the use of a property [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) which allows you to specify whether an element can be the subject of a mouse event.

In this case, you don't want the `.arrows` div to sustain mouse events, but you *do* want the `.arrows a` link element to. So you would use:

```
.arrows { pointer-events: none; }
.arrows a { pointer-events: all; }
```

Which would allow the link to be clicked, but for the rest of the `div` would force the mouse event (click) to **pass through** to elements beneath it (in this case, the `.buttons` link).

It's kind of a hack, but it works great.
See the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jVm2/15/)**.

Comment: I would love to use this, however IE doesn't cooperate.

Comment: True, if you look at the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Browser_compatibility) for pointer-events IE needs to be 11 or above.